# TextInputType.values, why does this exist?

Tags: flutter

I came across TextInputType.values in Flutter recently.
Does anyone know why this property exist and when to use?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType/values-constant.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help a lot if you make some app that have advanced customization, so you can show all possible values into a DropDown instead of writing all values one by one

for an example... Survey app, which Survey Maker can pick type of TextInputType (Number, Text, etc), with this .values will help you sort all of them automatically